# Mirror modifier popup saving settings

Tags: scripting, add-on

I am traying to make a mirror modifier popup, and i'ts working for the most part, but is saving the ''previous operations''

When i call it the first time it works as intended, i can choose the axis that it will mirror, but after if i call it again and press any button it will apply all the settings i have choosen previously. Can i reset it everytime or something?.

Also, isn't there any better way to make modifiers popup instead of having to make all of it manually?

````
class DC_MT_popup_mirror(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "popup.dc_mirror"
    bl_label = "Mirror Popup"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"

    
    def execute(self, context):
       pass
    
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager       
        return wm.invoke_popup(self, width=100)
        return {'FINISHED'}    
  
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        
        layout.label(text="Mirror")
                      
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('3dview.dc_mirror', text= "X").x_axis = True
        row.operator('3dview.dc_mirror', text= "Y").y_axis = True
        row.operator('3dview.dc_mirror', text= "Z").z_axis = True
    
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    
class DC_OT_mirror_add(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = '3dview.dc_mirror'
    bl_label = 'Mirror Axis'
        
    x_axis : bpy.props.BoolProperty(name = "X Axis", default = False)
    y_axis : bpy.props.BoolProperty(name = "Y Axis", default = False)
    z_axis : bpy.props.BoolProperty(name = "Z Axis", default = False)
    
    
    #pos_axis :bpy.props.IntProperty(name = "X Axis", default = -1)
    
    def execute(self, context):
        ob = context.object
        #x = x_axis        
              
                
        if "dcMirror" not in ob.modifiers:
            ob.modifiers.new(name="dcMirror", type='MIRROR')
            ob.modifiers["dcMirror"].show_on_cage = True
            ob.modifiers["dcMirror"].use_axis[0] = False
            ob.modifiers["dcMirror"].use_clip = True
                   

        if self.x_axis:
            ob.modifiers["dcMirror"].use_axis[0] = self.x_axis
            ob.modifiers["dcMirror"].use_bisect_axis[0] = self.x_axis
                       
         
        if self.y_axis:  
            ob.modifiers["dcMirror"].use_axis[1] = self.y_axis
            ob.modifiers["dcMirror"].use_bisect_axis[1] = self.y_axis
            ob.modifiers["dcMirror"].use_bisect_flip_axis[1] = self.y_axis
            
        if self.z_axis:  
            ob.modifiers["dcMirror"].use_axis[2] = self.z_axis
            ob.modifiers["dcMirror"].use_bisect_axis[2] = self.z_axis            
                    
        return {'FINISHED'}    
        
        
classes = (
    DC_MT_popup_mirror,
    DC_OT_mirror_add,   
)
register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()```
````

Comment: IMO would get out of habit of `collection[name]` in blender.  Above could be `mm = ob.modifiers.get("dcMirror")` and if this is `None` then  `mm =  ob.modifiers.new(name="dcMirror",   type='MIRROR')`  and then `mm.setting = value`   Code will look cleaner, and will only have to type "mm" (or whatever name is chosen) rather than `ob.modifiers["foo"]` each time.